# Angularjs ng-repeat array value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

```
myCtrl.Data.summary.account
```

if i print above model i get the output like below

```
["1","2","3","4","5"]
```

i want to use `ng-repeat` on this value, how to achive this?

I tried following code snippet using `ng-repeat` but it's not printing anything

```
<td ng-repeat="data in myCtrl.Data.summary.account">
    <tr>{{data}}</tr>
</td>
```

What mistake i made here? can anyone please point out this issue. How to fix this?

Comment: post myCtrl.Data

Comment: did you define `controllerAlias` as `myCtrl`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is `ng-repeat` not `ng-repet`

```
<td ng-repeat="data in myCtrl.Data.summary.account">
    <tr>{{data}}</tr>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Use `ng-repeat` instead of `ng-repet`

2) If you are using controllerAs syntax check if myCtrl is correct controller name in controllerAs value

3) If you are using `$scope` then you should create `$scope.myCtrl.Data.summary.account` in controller

Answer (score 0):

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){
 $scope.arr = ["1","2","3","4","5"]
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl"> 
<table>
  <tr>
    <td ng-repeat="data in arr"> 
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td >{{data}}
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table> 
    </td>
  </tr>
</table> 
</div>
```

cant use directly `<tr>`inside `<td>` . you need to create a table and add it there

```
<td ng-repeat="data in myCtrl.Data.summary.account">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>{{data}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should place the value in the columns and repeat for the rows. Your code should be in this format:

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in myCtrl.Data.summary.account">
    <td>{{data}}</td>
</tr>
```